# Why do I get "TypeError: this.X is not a function" when calling method from another method?

Tags: javascript

The following code generates the error `TypeError: this.SetValue is not a function`.

```
class FlightData {
    constructor(app)
    {
        this.app = app;

        this.websocket = new WebSocket('ws://'+window.location.hostname+':20225/flight_data');
        this.websocket.addEventListener('message', this.HandleSocketMessage);
    }

    SetValue(name, value)
    {
        console.log(name + ": " + value);
    }

    HandleSocketMessage(e)
    {
        this.SetValue("name", "value");
    }
}
```

If I do the following instead, it works. However I am trying to avoid closures (even though the one here is harmless) in my code:

```
this.websocket.addEventListener('message', e => {
        this.SetValue("name", "value");
});
```

Can someone please explain why the code at the top doesn't work and what I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to understand, but you need to bind the current context to the callback function. Otherwise, the context called is the callback's own.

```
this.websocket.addEventListener('message', this.HandleSocketMessage.bind(this) )
```

Comment: So clearly explained - I have spent ages on this, especially since I am considering abandoning my javascript framework (Vue) due to memory leak issues. I am rewriting a single component in completely raw javascript to determine whether the error is in my code or Vue, and I was completely stuck. Thankyou so much!